# RDD.pipe problems in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pipe, pyspark

I have a problem when using pyspark and pipe construct. I thought these should be equivalent.
case 1 :

```
 lines = sc.textFile("s3n://somestuff").map(lambda line: line)
 lines.saveAsTextFile("s3n://otherstuff")
```

and
case 2 :

```
   lines = sc.textFile("s3n://somestuff").pipe('cat')
   lines.saveAsTextFile("s3n://otherstuff")
```

The only difference I thought is the fact that pipe should operate on partitions while the map runs per line but the result should be equivalent here.

The case 1 of those runs in my case in about 50 seconds (1MM rows) 
& case 2 does not finish after 20 minutes. 
Am I missing something basic?

Just tried to also run the case 2 with pipe in equivalent scala code in shell. Finishes in about 6 seconds. The same thing in pyspark shell again does not finish in couple of minutes.

Since examples from documentation through `sc.parallelize` do work I do not think this is necessarily a bug. Maybe some parameter I am missing? Anybody experienced something similar?

Comment: Were you able to find the reason for the slowness?